# C++ drawing pixels question

Tags: c++, winapi, pixel

How to make window, or more like clipping region , where I'll be able to draw pixels?
It might use WinApi, however I don't want my project to look like winapi one, so it will have

```
int main(){}
```

instead of

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE ...
```

I have found an example, where I'm able to draw in console window

```
int main()
{
    COLORREF color = RGB(255,0,0); // COLORREF to hold the color info

    SetConsoleTitle("Pixel In Console?"); // Set text of the console so you can find the window

    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, "Pixel In Console?"); // Get the HWND
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd); // Get the DC from that HWND

    for( int i = 0 ; i < 50 ; i++ )
    {
    SetPixel(hdc, 5+i, 12, color); // SetPixel(HDC hdc, int x, int y, COLORREF color)
    }
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc); // Release the DC
    DeleteDC(hdc); // Delete the DC
    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

but instead of console, I want to draw on my selected region, which will hold focus ( when user clicks on it, etc ).

It would be also great to be able to handle simple keyboard/mouse events for this program, but it isn't my primary target here, maybe some other third party libraries will help with it.

I hope I've explained clearly what I want to do, but English isn't my native language, so I'm very sorry for any missunderstandings.

I will be thankfull for any help.

---

As I'm using this site first time, I'm sorry for little spam or messages in wrong places, as I'm not sure where to post my next messages :-)
So what i wanted to write, is:

"
Otherwise, how does Allegro/SDL create window? They use assembler calls or shell ones? I'll be much happier, when I'll be able to create window from scratch, no matter how much work does it take :) 
"

Comment: If you want to create a window use WINAPI there are plenty of examples on the net and on msdn.microsoft.com. If you use WINAPI your program will look like it uses WINAPI. Whats the deal?

Comment: main() is starting function for console applications. You don't want console, so you have to use WinMain.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Yeah, I believe that to be correct. Actually, `WinMain` is a macro which will be replaced to use the correct windowed `main` depending on whether the application is compiled in UNICODE mode or ASCII mode.

Comment: @gablin @Dialecticus I'm sure you could write a console app with WinMain as your main, and I'm sure you could write a windowed app with main as your main and the appropriate parameters.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Just out of interest, I google it and found this link: http://comsci.liu.edu/~murali/win32gui/Win32Apps.htm However, it only shows how to generate a console window using "window" mode, but not windows using "console" mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't like this - in Windows, you have to create a window, then override WM_PAINT message, then draw what you have to draw when you are called from the system.  That's old-school way of doing things, and it isn't so bad.

Some interesting and relevant links:

http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/bitmaps.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66250/BeginPaint-EndPaint-or-GetDC-ReleaseDC.aspx

If you are really into avoiding all that, try [popcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/popcapframework/).  Learning curve involved there maybe steeper, so you probably really want to stick with GDI and HWND no matter how hard and confusing it might look in the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to try OpenGL coupled with either [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) or [glut](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/).
With OpenGL you will be able to handle all the things that are related to graphics processing (2D/3D rendering), and the role of the GLFW library for instance is to add some functionalities like: window management, event management, timers, threads etc.

Personnal note, go for GLFW because glut isn't maintained anymore I think...

Comment: True. GLFW rocks, same for SDL. (And GLUT, not to mention being discontinued, has a very weird API...)

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise, how does Allegro/SDL create window? They use assembler calls or shell ones? I'll be much happier, when I'll be able to create window from scratch, no matter how much work does it take :)

Answer (score 1):

**Problem with your code:**
I tried out your code and i found that the line seemed to appear in some instance of its execution, but sometimes, when I execute it, the red line isn't found! From what I understand it is because you kept these 3 statements:

```
// Set text of the console so you can find the window
SetConsoleTitle("Pixel In Console?"); 
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, "Pixel In Console?"); // Get the HWND
HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd); // Get the DC from that HWND
```

But Windows only updates your window name after a little time, so if you make these statements execute one after the other, the `HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, "Pixel In Console?");` statement cant find such a window, because Windows takes time to update the title as done by : `SetConsoleTitle("Pixel In Console?");`

**Solution:**
You can either keep a `Sleep(int);` (include `windows.h`) or use:

`HWND hwnd = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass",NULL); // Get the HWND`

instead of

`SetConsoleTitle("Pixel In Console?"); // Set text of the console so you can find the window
    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, "Pixel In Console?"); // Get the HWND`

Here is an **example program:**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include<conio.h>`
#include<iostream.h>`

POINT p;    //structure with coordinates to mouse location`

void main()
{
    COLORREF color = RGB(255,0,0); // COLORREF to hold the color info`

    HWND hwnd = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass",NULL); // Get the HWND
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd); // Get the DC from that HWND

    for( int i = 0 ; i < 400 ; i++ )
    {
        for(int j=0;j<50;j++)
            SetPixel(hdc, i, j, color);
    }
    while(1)
    {
          GetCursorPos(&p);
          ScreenToClient(hwnd,&p);
          cout<<p.x<<' '<<p.y;
          clrscr();
          if(GetAsyncKeyState(1)) //checks if left mouse button is pressed
          {
                //fool around with these functions:
                SetPixel(hdc,p.x,p.y,color); 
                //LineTo(hdc,p.x,p.y);
                //Rectangle(hdc,200,200,p.x,p.y);
                Sleep(10);
          }
    }
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc); // Release the DC
    DeleteDC(hdc); // Delete the DC
    system("pause");
}
```

*This is my first answer. I hope I helped and it took a lot of searching to find these functions
besides I think I learned more from your script than I showed you :)*

Comment: Is it possible to wait until window title is updated if you already got `hwnd`?

Comment: Once you successfully created your hwnd variable, it doesn't matter what your window title is! So **feel free to change your title** it :)

Comment: Don't call `DeleteDC(hdc)` when you obtained it by calling `GetDC`. `ReleaseDC` suffices. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-deletedc).

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: You should use a graphics framework / widgeting toolkit in order to create a window, and start from there.

Then, depending on what framework you use, you'll then create the window and modify the pixels according to its reference.

I recommend **SDL** (small, probably exactly what you need), **Allegro** (similar) or **Qt** (largeish).

Comment: I need library which doesn't use/isn't mostly based at graphics card, as it will have to work on VGASAVE mode, but other way, how does Allegro/SDL create window? They use assembler calls or shell ones? I'll be much happier, when I'll be able to create window from scratch, no matter how much work does it take :)

Comment: SDL is okay, use `SDL_SetVideoMode(x,y,bpp, SDL_SWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUFFER)`.

Comment: Is same thing possibile with allegro5 ?

Comment: Of course. See http://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/graphics.html and http://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/primitives.html . The manual is usually the right place to quickly assess the capabilities of a library.