# Windows Console Pixels

Tags: c, windows, console, pixel

I have seen old programs that run the Windows console and draw colored pixels in the console window to produce a low-level graphic interface. [1] How is it possible to print pixels to the console instead of text, and [2] how is it possible to get the mouse position in terms of what pixel on the console? [3] Also, how can one determine whether a specific key is pressed?

Thanks.

Comment: You may find some answers in this related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378642/c-pixels-in-console-window :)

Comment: That thread helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that you want some function in "ncurses"(which is a library on linux) on windows system. 
You can look at this: http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/