# How to get pixels of char C++

Tags: c++, char, pixel, tetris

I'm making Tetris game , and while displaying shapes on console i faced a problem;
at first just displaying the shapes  were all shifted to the left ignoring the space
so i made a condition to move the cursor with the space so as to display the characters at the right place , but this seems to destroy the shape because i don't know the size of the pixels of the character.

```
void ANIMATION(int box[8][8])
{
    char ▊ = 219;
    double x = 20,y=30;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        gotoXY(x,y);
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            if (box[i][j] == 1)
            {

                cout << ▊;
            }

            else
                gotoXY((x+=0.35), y);
        }
        y++;
        cout << endl;
    }
    x = 20;
    y = 30;
    Sleep(1000);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        gotoXY(x, y);
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            if (box[i][j] == 1)
            {

                cout << ' ';
            }
            else 
                gotoXY((x += 0.35), y);

        }
        y++;
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause>null");
}
```

Comment: This is OS depended, for which operating system you're developing this game?

Comment: windows 7 (windows console :visual studio)

Comment: This is a nice thread then ["pixels in console window"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378642/c-pixels-in-console-window).

Comment: If you are going to make such a game, it simply has to use a font where all characters have the same size.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the OS you are using:

In Windows you can find what the character size is by using
[GetConsoleFontSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683165%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

In Linux you may want to look at something like [freetype](http://www.freetype.org/)